# Find largest number that satisfy given constraints

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms

Let's define $F(x)$ for positive integer $x$ as a product of factorials of its digits. For example, $F(135) = 1!*3!*5!=720$

Now Given a decimal number $A$ consisting of $N$ digits that contains at least one digit larger than 1. This number may possibly start with leading zeroes. Then we should find maximum positive number $X$ satisfying following two conditions:

**1. $X$ doesn't contain neither digit $0$ nor digit $1$.**

**2.  $F(X)=F(A)$**

I need to find maximum such number.

**Example** : Let $N=4$ and $A=1234$ then maximum possible integer satisfying the conditions above is $33222$ because $F(1234) = 1!*2!*31*4!=288=F(33222)$.

How can I find this number ?

Comment: Do you want some sort of formula or just way to work it out?

Comment: Please clarify your first condition, the double negative is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following factorisations of factorials:

- 9! = 7! 3! 3! 2!
- 8! = 7! 2! 2! 2!
- 7! = 7!
- 6! = 5! 3!
- 5! = 5!
- 4! = 3! 2! 2!
- 3! = 3!
- 2! = 2!

It is easy to see that this is the maximum number of digits you can obtain from each digit factorial. The solution then is to factorise each of the digit factorials in this fashion and just use the digits found in sorted order. For example, if A=549, we have 5->5; 4->3,2,2; 9->7,3,3,2. Sorting the digits, we get X=75333222.